# Trying to install packages which use (a private) git repository from inside a docker container fails

Tags: git, docker, ssh, npm-install

In our setup we have an automated build system. The build is actually done inside a docker (so the host server doesn't have to have all libraries installed). The installation *should* use the credentials of the host os' user.

The system works either when I do not use the docker image and manually call `npm i --only=production`. Or it works when I remove any dependency on private git repositories. However when I use both I get a "warning"/error. I first am given the "question" that the host is not on the known host list (which I do know is for my local machine where I test it on). Followed by an error `git@HOST: Permission denied (publickey).`

The docker file is as follow:

```
FROM node:12-alpine
RUN apk update
RUN apk upgrade
RUN apk add rsync
RUN apk add git less openssh

RUN mkdir /javascript
WORKDIR /javascript

ENTRYPOINT npm i --only=production
```

The docker is run with these parameters:

```
sudo docker run -it --volume=/home/paul/PROJECTDIR/javascript:/javascript --volume=/home/paul/.ssh/:/root/.ssh/ IMAGEID
```

An exempt of the package.json (actually the offending line):

```
"dependencies": {
  "configuration-loader": "git+ssh://git@HOST",
}
```

As I can easily do `npm i --only=production` from outside the docker it must be that the docker is not reading the ssh information correctly? I've double checked but `/home/paul/.ssh` contains a correct `id_rsa` `id_rsa.pub` and `known_hosts` file.

So what is going on here? Why is the install from docker not reading the ssh information? Am I binding the incorrect internal location? - What location should I use?

I've also tried changing the entrypoint to `sh` and then checking what's in `~/.ssh` (and that that directory exists) - which shows perfectly fine the keys.

---

For debugging I changed the entrypoint to `sh` and manually tried to install (same errors) but using `printenv` showed:

```
GIT_SSH_COMMAND=ssh -Tvv
NODE_VERSION=12.18.3
HOSTNAME=3dd43e45c090
YARN_VERSION=1.22.4
SHLVL=2
HOME=/root
TERM=xterm
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
PWD=/javascript
```

Furthermore using `ENV GIT_SSH_COMMAND ssh -Tvv` reported messages like:

```
debug1: identity file /home/node/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
```

And when I changed the volume to not link inside `/root` but instead into `/home/node`, the debug message changed to:

```
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
```

To check how the home directory is linked running:

```
ls -alrth /home
```

Shows (when binding the volume to `/root`):

```
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        4.0K Jul 28 21:24 .
drwxr-sr-x    1 node     node        4.0K Aug 31 09:07 node
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        4.0K Aug 31 09:07 ..
```

When bound to `/home/node` the same entries appear, just `node` is after `..` (though time is reported the same so it must be fluke).

It seems to actually enforce a new ssh key or something? That if it already finds one it enforces a local key?

Comment: Is `/home/node` a symlink? What does a `ls -alrth /home` return in both your scenarios?

Comment: @VonC they are "equal".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok this is with a lot of help from @VonC and by far the least favourite solution I would do. But how I solved it is by binding both the `/home` and `/home/node` to the external home directory.

```
sudo docker run -it \
    --volume=/home/paul/PROJECTDIR/javascript:/javascript \
    --volume=/home/paul/.ssh/:/root/.ssh/ \
    --volume=/home/paul/.ssh/:/home/node/.ssh IMAGEID
```

Ugly, but working.

Answer (score 1):

Start with adding to your Dockerfile a line with:

```
ENV GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -Tvv'
```

You will then see if there are error messages or from where Docker is taking its SSH key: that can help to understand what is going on.

Comment: I notice it says a lot of debug with: `debug1: identity file /home/node/.ssh/id_rsa type -1` - does this mean it considers `/home/node/.ssh/` as directory? - why? I can't see why it would consider that over the user profile?

Comment: @paul23 Maybe because `$HOME` is redefined in the context of npm execution?

Comment: weirder still, if I change the volume to point to `/home/node` instead of root the same debug error comes but now with `debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type`

Comment: @paul23 You should try and call a script (instead of directly `npm` in your `ENTRYPOINT`) which would first display the environment variables, with the command `env`, and then call `npm`. That would give you more clues.