# ssh key in Dockerfile returning Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: docker, ssh, gitlab, dockerfile, docker-buildkit

I'm trying to build a Docker image using DOCKER_BUILDKIT which involves cloning a private remote repository from GitLab, with the following lines of my Dockerfile being used for the git clone:

```
# Download public key for gitlab.com
RUN mkdir -p -m 0700 ~/.ssh && ssh-keyscan gitlab.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
RUN --mount=type=ssh git clone git@gitlab.com:*name_of_repo* *download_location*
```

However, when I run the docker build command using:

```
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build --ssh default --tag test:local .
```

I get the following error when it is trying to do the git clone:

```
git@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I've set up the ssh access successfully on the machine I'm trying to build this image on, and both the `ssh -T git@gitlab.com` and trying to clone the repository outside of the Docker build work just fine.

I've had a look around but can't find any info on what might be causing this specific issue - any pointers much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have an ssh-agent running and did you add the ssh key to it? See https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/agent

Comment: I had an agent running, but I think I hadn't added the ssh key to it! It works now. Happy to either delete this question or if you want to write up an answer I can accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have an SSH agent running and that you added your private key to it.

Depending on your platform, the commands may vary but since it's tagged `gitlab` I will assume that Linux is your platform.

Verify that you have an SSH agent running with `echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK` or `echo $SSH_AGENT_SOCK` if both echo an empty string, you most likely do not have an agent running.

To start an agent you can usually type:

```
eval `ssh-agent`
```

Next, you can verify what key are added (if any) with:

```
ssh-add -l
```

If the key you need is not listed, you can add it with:

```
ssh-add /path/to/your/private-key
```

Then you should be good to go.

More info here: https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/agent

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

For testing, use a non-encrypted private SSH key (meaning you don't have to manage an `ssh-agent`, which is only needed for encrypted private key passphrase caching)

And use `ssh -Tv git@gitlab.com` to check *where* SSH is looking for your key.

Then, in your Dockerfile, add before the line with `git clone`:

```
ENV GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -Tv'
```

You will see again *where* Docker/SSH is looking when executing `git clone` with an SSH URL.

I [suggested as much here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63653070/6309), and there were some mounting folders missing then.